# How can a plant have pure graphite cell walls instead of cellulose?

Tags: biology, chemistry, biochemistry

So like, how could a plant extract carbon out of other organic molecules and make their cell walls out of graphite instead of cellulose?

Comment: Why would it? Graphite is horrible, terrible, no good as a replacement for cellulose. (And you have it backwards; to get a graphite-ish material starting from cellulose you don't take the carbon out, but rather you take the oxygen and hydrogen out. Which is a routine process that was and is done when [making charcoal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcoal).)

Comment: Well, it didn't evolve naturally, the plant was genetically engineered to produce graphite because a scientist felt like doing it, it has no actual useful purpose. Secondly, what is an enzyme that can catalyze the pyrolysis process in charcoal making?

Comment: No enzyme, just heat and combustion in oxygen poor environment. But what you get is not really graphite, it is sort-of graphite-ish. In practice, synthetic graphite is made on large scale from carborundum using the [Acheson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acheson_process).

Comment: No like, how could a hexagonal form of carbon be produced in life, you know how?

Comment: You keep asking which enzyme would do something. That's not a worldbuilding problem. It's either a patent waiting to be filed in or a PhD in chemistry waiting to happen.

Comment: Aww man, but it was a worldbuilding problem, plants made of pure carbon were pretty neat, I was wondering how that could be possible...

Answer (score 4):

Plant cell walls are not simple sheets of cellulose. Like most biological structures, they're fairly complicated:

[image: Image from Wikimedia Commons, by Lady of Hats]
[Picture from Wikimedia Commons, by Lady of Hats](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Plant_cell_wall_diagram-en.svg)

A cell wall composed of graphite or graphene sheets would not be sufficiently permeable to allow a cell to stay alive.

Keeping the current design, but replacing the cellulose microfibrils with carbon nanotubes would be closer to biological plausibility. The genetic engineering needed to do this is way beyond our current capabilities, so nobody can tell you just how it would be done.